# Traic switching in 3+ quadrant

Tags: triac, switching

I am controlling fan speed using Triac phase control with a circuit similar to this. The problem that i am facing is that my triac burned out after using it for 2 3 days and after burning it will remain switched on continuously without gate trigger.
I concluded that i am triggering it in 1- and 3+ quadrant resulting in slow degradation, and eventual shorting of MT1 and MT2.[image]

Referred following document for 3+ quadrant switching details.  (http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN_GOLDEN_RULES.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Triggering a triac in QI/QIII is not going to cause "slow degradation".

More likely you're allowing it to greatly overheat or there is a voltage transient that has occurred.

Comment: what about QIV (3+)? It can not be voltage transient as it has happened twice with same characteristics. Please note that i have inverted MT1 and MT2 terminals in circuit

Comment: The quadrant doesn't matter (to the triac)- it either triggers or it doesn't. Neither should damage the triac. Billions of triac light dimmers all over the world uses those quadrants and minor variations on that circuit.

Comment: i read this fact about 3+ quadrant in document by NXP(link above). Can the heating be observed from Triac surface if overheat is the case.

Comment: First, the phenomenon mentioned causes harder triggering (failing off or half-waving), not failing on, and secondly, you're not using it in that quadrant (what most people call quadrant IV)- the gate voltage has the same polarity as the MT2 (what you show as MT1) always, so what is called 1+ and 3- in that document, and quadrants I and III by most everyone else. Fans are inductive and do not have rapid di/dt on switch-on.

Comment: I am using this dim a dimmable LED bulb

Comment: In the case of a dimmable LED you could be exceeding the di/dt rating of the triac because of capacitors in the LED supply. Try adding an LC EMI filter as would normally be found in a commercial light dimmer. The inductance will slow the rate-of-rise of the current and prevent hot spots on the die.